# Prove or disprove by induction that $a_n = b_n $

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

I have this task that gives me really a hard time:

For $$ n \in \mathbb{N_0} $$

$a_n$ is defined as $$ a_n= (-1)^{(n+1)}+ 1 + -3n + 2n^2 $$

and $b_n$ as:
$$ b_n =\begin{cases}
          a_n \quad &\text{for} \, 0 ≤ n ≤ 2, \\
          b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}+8 \quad &\text{for} \, 3 ≤ n \\
     \end{cases}
$$

Prove or disprove by induction that $ a_n = b_n $ for $n \in \mathbb{N} $

Can anyone help me with this? I have a hard time finding the right induction for this and its kinda important that i understand it. Would be great to see how to approach this properly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before trying to prove or disprove it, I'd use Excel to check the first 100 or 1000 values, myself.....

Comment: Is it intentional that the formula for $a_n$ has separate $1 + (-3)$ terms, or is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: @Bungo i updated it and removed the () from -3. I just thought it would be more clearer, now it is exactly as stated in the task.

Comment: @Bungo there was also an n variable missing. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @fleablood nope, i just changed it now from "if" to "for". But 3≤n is stated like that in the task

Comment: Use as base case $n =3$ ($n=1,2$ it is true by definition.  Inductions step assume in true for all values up to an arbitrary $k \ge 3$.  Then you have that $b_{n+1} = b_{n} + b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}+8 = a_{n} + a_{n-1} -a_{n_2} + 8 $.  try to prove that that is is  equal to $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: @fleablood okay, i'm gonna try it to solve it this way. I'll report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you just need  to verify that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ satisfies the same  recurrence relation:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}+8.$$
And it is straightforward to find that's true. Let's see how to verify this point:

$$\begin{split}
&a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}+8\\
={}&(-1)^n+1-3(n-1)+2(n-1)^2+(-1)^{n-1}+1-3(n-2)+2(n-2)^2\\
&-(-1)^{n-2}-1+3(n-3)-2(n-3)^2+8\\
={}&2n^2-3n+1-(-1)^{n-2}\\
={}&a_n
\end{split}$$
Suppose that $a_k=b_k$ for all $k\leq n$, then
$$\begin{split}
b_{n+1}&=b_{n}+b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}+8\\
&=a_n+a_{n-2}-a_{n-2}+8\\
&=a_{n+1}.
\end{split}$$
According to the **Strong Induction Principle**, we know $a_n=b_n(\forall n\geq 0)$

Comment: thanks for you answer. However, would you give an example how to do that properly?

Comment: Just plug $n, n-1, n-2, n-3$ into the formula for $a_n$.  $a_n= (-1)^{(n+1)}+ 1 + -3n + 2n^2$ and $a_{n-1} = (-1)^{(n-1)+1} + 1 -3(n-1) + 2(n-1)^2$ and $a_{n-2} =  (-1)^{(n-2)+1} + 1 -3(n-2) + 2(n-2)^2$ and $a_{n-3} = (-1)^{(n-3)+1} + 1 -3(n-3) + 2(n-3)^2$.

Comment: You shouldn't have edited to go into so much detail.  You should live *some* work for the OP to do.

Comment: So we showed that $ a_n = b_n $ with that. As @fleablood mentioned, the base case is 3, where $ a_n = b_n $. So the induction hypothesis is  therefor $ b_{n+1} = _+_{−1}−_{−2}+8 $. And according to the Induction Principle, we can say that$ a_{n+1} = b_{n+1} $, is that so correct or do i need to show $a_{n+1}$ as well? Thank you all so much, it helps a lot

Comment: @fleablood what im trying so ask is basically: Is it mathematical correct for the induction hypothesis and the final induction to say $ a_{n+1} = b_{n+1} $, since we already showed in the induction base that $ a_n = b_n$?