# Proof verification: Is my induction proof correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

Can anyone proof read my induction proof for this particular task?

For $$ n \in \mathbb{N_0} $$

$a_n$ is defined as $$ a_n= (-1)^{(n+1)}+ 1 + (-3n) + 2n^2 $$

and $b_n$ as:
$$ b_n =\begin{cases}
          a_n \quad &\text{if} \, 0 ≤ n ≤ 2, \\
          b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}+8 \quad &\text{if} \, 3 ≤ n \\
     \end{cases}
$$

Prove or disprove by induction that $ a_n = b_n $
$$Induction Base: n=0,n=1,n=2,n=3$$

$$b_0 =a_0 =(−1)0+1 +1−3·0+2·02 =−1+1=0$$

$$b1 =a1 =(−1)1+1 +1−3·1+2·12 =1+1−3+2=1$$

$$b_2 =a_2 =(−1)2+1 +1−3·2+2·22 =−1+1−6+8=2 
$$
$$b_3 =b_2 +b_1 −b_0 +8=2+1−0+8=11 
$$

Induction Hypothesis: For all $k \in \mathbb {N_0}$ and k<n and n≥3 for some random but fixed $n \in \mathbb{N_0} $  a_k = b_k

Induction Step: $bn =b_{n−1} +b_{n−2} −b_{n−3} +8=(−1)^n +1−3(n−1)+2(n−1)$

$+(−1)^n−1 +1−3(n−2)+2(n−2)^2−(−1)^{n−2} +1−3(n−3)+2(n−3)^2+8$

$=(−1)(−1)(−1)^{n−2} +1−3(n−1)+2(n−1)^2 +(−1)^{n−1} +1−3(n−2)+2(n−2)^2$

$−(−1)^{n−2} −1+3(n−3)−2(n−3)^2 +8 = 1(−1)^{n−2} +1−3n+3+2n^2 −2^{n+1}+1(−1)^{n−1} −3n+6+2n^2 −4n+4$

$−(−1)^{n−2} +3n−9−2n^2 −6n+9+8= (11) =(−1)(−1)(−1)^{n−1} +9−3n+2n^2 −4n+2+2n^2 −8n+8−2n^2 +12n−18$

$=(−1)^{n+1} +1−3n+2n^2 =a_n $

Comment: Any particular reason for the "$+1+(-3)$" in the definition of $a_n$?, as opposed to simply a $-2$?

Comment: @Troposphere, when I look more closely at the example calculations of $b0$, $b1$, and $b2$ (which should, of course, be typeset as $b_0$, $b_1$, and $b_2$), it looks like the OP meant $+1+(-3)n$. The OP should edit the correction(s) in.

Comment: @BarryCipra, ye there is some weird formation problem going on. I need to recheck everything, so many numbers. I guess its also about my induction itself, like the hypothesis and the base cases

Comment: @BarryCipra: Hmm, yes, that matches with the Jordan decomposition of the recurrence matrix too.

Comment: @JohnGam, you could start by cleaning up some of the obvious typos, such as the missing "_"s and "^"s for subscripts and superscripts. That alone will help make your post more readable.  Also, making sure there's a line break between your calculations of "b0" and "b1," as you did for the b2 and b3, will help.

Comment: @BarryCipra i did now fixed the issues mentioned above. I will update the rest as well

Comment: In addition to what Barry says, while you do all that work, also _insert some English words_ to explain how your formulas relate to each other. Proofs are supposed to be _explanations_ of why the thing to be proved is true, not symbolic riddles where the reader has to figure out how the formulas relate to anything.

Comment: @JohnGam, I see you've fixed some (though not all) of the subscripts. The superscripts (i.e., exponents) still need attention.  And take care to use curly brackets around your "n+1"s, so that don't wind up with things like $(-1)^0+1$ when you mean $(-1)^{0+1}$. Also, notice you've got a dangling dollar sign down near the bottom of your post! Finally, I agree wholeheartedly with Troposphere's advice.

Comment: @BarryCipra i think that should be it. As for explanations, well i use the common pattern for the induction proof. I have the base case, the induction hypothesis and the final induction step. I tried to make each step more clear, hopefully this works now better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove or disprove by induction that $a_n = b_n $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4177022/prove-or-disprove-by-induction-that-a-n-b-n)

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose a bit cleaner alternative proof by strong induction.

You have already showed that these two sequences agree on first four terms $n=0,1, 2, 3.$ Then directly compute $a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}+8$ using the given formula, and make sure it is equal to $a_n$ for all $n\ge 3.$ Thus, both $(a_n), (b_n)$ satisfies the same recurrence relation. Fix an integer $k\ge 3,$ and assume the result: $a_n =b_n$ holds for all $3\le n\le k,$ then
\begin{align}
a_{k+1}-b_{k+1}
& = (a_{k}+a_{k-1}-a_{k-2}+8)-(b_{k}+b_{k-1}-b_{k-2}+8)\\
& = (a_k-b_k)+(a_{k-1}-b_{k-1})-(a_{k-2}-b_{k-2})\\
& = 0
\end{align}
proves the result for $n=k+1.$

Comment: isn't my induction also a strong induction proof? If not, would you like to tell me the diference between mine and yours and what particullary makes yours a strong one and not mine?

Comment: I didn't went through all the details of your proof. Using the fact that $(a_n)$ satisfies the same recurrence relation makes things clearer.

Comment: How do you unfold $a_{k+1}$ to $a_k+a_{k-1}-a_{k-2}+8$ when you're still in the middle of proving that the $a_i$s satisfy the recurrence in the first place? It looks like you're essentially assuming the conclusion here.